# Regular expression to match only numbers

Tags: regex

I want to match only individual numbers from the following sample input:

```
[2,4,7,9-11]
```

Regular expression should match 2,4 & 7, but not 9-11.

Comment: So, your delimiter is a comma?

Comment: And what about this case:  `[2,32,4,7,9-11]`? Will it match 32?

Comment: Where are you implementing this? PHP, Bash, some text editor?

Comment: The input type is ambiguous in your post.  Is this input a string or an array?  This is an important factor in developing the best regex pattern.  What language/environment is this regex meant to run in?  Even if you have received a satisfying answer, improving your question will benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single character matching this might suffice. `\b` is a *word boundary* and `\d` indicates that we're looking for a *single digit*.

```
\b\d\b
```

If you would like to omit single Zeros then you would do something like this with a custom range:

```
\b[1-9]\b
```

If you're okay with double-digit numbers and zero, then you would add a plus `+` (*means more than one*) to the original:

```
\b\d+\b
```

To match any single number from the provided that would not part of a range you would use boundaries and look-arounds:

```
\b(?<!-)\d(?!-)\b
```

You can [learn more about Regex here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: But it will match 9 too.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I think their meaning is to find individual numbers and not ranges, not specifically 9-11.

Answer (score 1):

Your targets have non hyphens fore and aft:

```
(?<!-)\b\d+\b(?!-)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ANV4vPq5Oj).

Comment: It's working partially.
For example, in this case it is matching 1 from 11, Which it should not.

Comment: @BhushanKhajone I've added word boundaries, and a demo link to show it working.